# Android 13 - How to save a pdf to external storage?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, storage-access-framework, android-13

My app needs to download PDF bills for customers, and I'm targeting Android 13 for this release. I've noticed that the storage permissions have changed, and now there are three new permissions: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, and READ_MEDIA_AUDIO. However, there isn't a specific permission for downloading documents, and I'm unsure about the right approach to achieve this.

Should I use the Storage Access Framework (SAF)? I found examples on how to read files from external storage but not how to write to it.

Here are some key details about my app:

- The app's main activity displays a list of settlements.
- When the user clicks on an item in the list, a custom dialog is
  opened, which provides details about the payroll and a button to
  download the PDF bill.
- The bills are stored in an S3 bucket, and I currently use the
  document URL with the DownloadManager API to initiate the download.

Comment: "Should I use the Storage Access Framework (SAF)?" -- IMHO, yes. "I found examples on how to read files from external storage but not how to write to it" -- it is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#perform-operations). It is also covered in [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) and [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore), among other books and training.

Comment: `However, there isn't a specific permission for downloading documents, `Indeed there is not and there has never been one.

Comment: `noticed that the storage permissions have changed` Indeed you always needed a storage WRITE permission  to create/write files. But not anymore for Android 13+ devices.

Comment: `DownloadManager API to initiate the download.` DownloadManager has never needed a storage WRITE permission to store files on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I've seen the example, but I was a little confused because I had the URL of a file I wanted to download and resultData also has a URI. I assume that the URI in resultData refers to the folder where I want to download my pdf in this case, am I correct?

Comment: @JuanGil: No, it represents the file (or equivalent) of where you want to download the PDF.